# Is there a way to make a function get a random number twice from the same variable

Tags: python

I am trying to make a dice that you can ask you if you want to generate a new random number *(The idea is from https://knightlab.northwestern.edu/2014/06/05/five-mini-programming-projects-for-the-python-beginner/)*.

The first run works but it doesn't generate a new number but prints the same one. Is there a way to do it?

My code:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,6)
def rollDie():
    print(number)
    answer = input("Do you want to roll the die again? Answer with Y or N")
    if answer == "Y":
        rollDie()
    elif answer == "N":
        print("bye!")

rollDie()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more bothersome problem from my perspective is the use of *recursion* in this context.  I see it often with beginner Python code in either this context, or as an error handling mechanism, and it is a bad pattern to be teaching new programmers.  This should be handled with a simple loop:

```
import random

def rollDie():
    while True:
        number = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(number)

        answer = input("Do you want to roll the die again? Answer Y or N: ")

        if answer.upper() == 'N':
            print("Bye!")
            break

rollDie()
```

Rather than calling `rollDie()` again recursively.

Comment: What did you change here? All I see is that you put the code  in the function into a while loop and put an anwser.upper

Comment: @aafr, I removed the recursive call to `rollDie()` from within `rollDie()`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that `number` is only defines once. `number` is an integer, and integers are immutable, so unless you redefine the variable, its value will never change.

In order to accomplish the dice throw simulation, relocate your `number = random.randint(1,6)` from the top of your code to inside your function:

From:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,6)
def rollDie():
    print(number)
    answer = input("Do you want to roll the die again? Answer with Y or N")
    if answer == "Y":
        rollDie()
    elif answer == "N":
        print("bye!")

rollDie()
```

To:

```
import random

def rollDie():
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    print(number)
    answer = input("Do you want to roll the die again? Answer with Y or N")
    if answer == "Y":
        rollDie()
    elif answer == "N":
        print("bye!")

rollDie()
```